# Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION not working

Tags: sql-server

When I create table UV (table that contains the foreign keys) the table works without errors.

But when I want to update or delete some foreign key .. the query doesn't work. So I figured out that I must add `on update cascade` `on delete cascade` on each foreign key.

The problem is I have 2 columns foreign keys references for the primary key in table formateur()

**That's my creation**

```
create table formateur
(
    num_formateur int primary key ,
    nom_formateur varchar(30),
    prenom_formateur varchar(30),
    telephone nvarchar(12),
    adresse nvarchar(300),
    typee varchar(30)
)

create table formation
(
    num_formation int primary key,
    nom_formation varchar(30),
    nombre_UV int,
    motdepasse nvarchar(30)
)

create table UV
(
    num_UV int primary key,
    nom_UV varchar(30),
    masse_horaire_prevue int,
    num_formateur_enseignant int foreign key  references formateur(num_formateur) on update cascade on delete cascade  ,
    num_formateur_responsable int foreign key   references formateur(num_formateur) on update cascade on delete cascade ,
    num_formation int foreign key   references formation(num_formation) on update cascade on delete cascade
)


insert into formateur values('1','nom_formateur','prenom_formateur','342343412','adresse','responsable')
insert into formateur values('2','nom_formateur','prenom_formateur','342343412','adresse','responsable')
insert into formateur values('3','nom_formateur','prenom_formateur','342343412','adresse','enseignant')
insert into formateur values('4','nom_formateur','prenom_formateur','342343412','adresse','enseignant')


insert into formation values ('1','nom_formation','123','1')
insert into formation values ('2','nom_formation','123','1')
insert into formation values ('3','nom_formation','123','1')
insert into formation values ('4','nom_formation','123','1')

insert into UV values('1','nom_UV','23','3','1','1')
insert into UV values('2','nom_uv','43','4','2','1')
insert into UV values('3','nom_uv','63','4','2','1')
insert into UV values('4','nom_uv','73','4','2','1')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your references try to delete records from the same table, and those two columns potentially can reference the same record (and it's an issue).

You can either create a trigger on DELETE instead of making FKs with CASCADE option and delete records from [formateur], or just create separate tables for each column (formateur1 and formateur2, something like that).

Also, I've noticed your data in UV doesn't have unique values in columns `num_formateur_enseignant` and `num_formateur_responsable`.

Are you sure you want to delete the records since they can be reused in different rows?

If you use the trigger

```
CREATE OR ALTER TRIGGER TRG_UV_DELETE
on UV
INSTEAD OF DELETE
AS
BEGIN
    set nocount on

    DELETE UV
    FROM UV
        INNER JOIN DELETED
            ON UV.num_UV = DELETED.num_UV

    DELETE formation
    FROM formation
        INNER JOIN DELETED
            ON formation.num_formation = DELETED.num_formation

    delete formateur
    from formateur
    INNER JOIN DELETED
        ON formateur.num_formateur IN (DELETED.num_formateur_enseignant, DELETED.num_formateur_responsable) 
END
```

and fill out your table like this:

```
insert into UV values('1','nom_UV','23','1','2','1')
insert into UV values('2','nom_uv','43','3','4','2')
```

trigger will work.